# How do I keep the colour of the traced image opaque? (Illustrator CS6)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, transparency

I image traced a JPG file as a High Fidelity Photo then chose Expand. I was able to remove the white background, only keeping the details of the image. However, when I change the background colour, the image also changes colour with it, as if it were transparent. I'd like to know how to retain the original colour of the image/vector despite the colour of the background. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Are

[image: The original image colour on the left]

[image]

Comment: Could you screenshot the "Transparency" preferences? `Window -> Transparency` Be sure to expand it using the double arrows and to have your figure selected.

Comment: @2rB I added the screenshot to the question, hope that works!

Comment: I see nothing wrong there. The next thing to check is if "Overprint Fill" and/or "Overprint stroke" is selected in the Attributes panel `View -> Attributes`.

Comment: @2rB Overprint Fill is not checked and Overprint Stroke seems to be grayed out with a - symbol checked inside.

Comment: When you say you changed the background, what did you do to change the background?  If you changed it in the document setup: simulate paper, and you have Overprint Preview enabled, then that could be the source of the problem.

Comment: @BillyKerr I go to Document Setup, check Simulate Colored Paper and select the top box (white as default) to change the colour.

I just noticed that the same thing happens with the color of the image regardless of what image I use, even if its an unprocessed JPG.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the reply! I suppose I would have to find an alternative way to change the background. Do you have any recomendations?

Comment: @Are I've added an answer now. Yes, then that is exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Further to the comments, the problem is because you changed the background colour in the settings: Simulate Colored Paper. If you do that, and also have the Overprint Preview enabled, this will cause the problem. You can toggle the Overprint Preview on/off by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

Note that the option to simulate paper is for showing what will happen if you print on coloured paper. So, I'd suggest you don't use that option unless you specifically want to do that.  Also if you print using this option on white paper, the background colour will not print! It's not a real background colour - it's only an on-screen simulation.

**TLDR:** Don't use this option if you want the background colour to be printed, or to be an actual part of the graphic.

Instead, create a filled rectangle as the background, and lower it to the bottom of the layer stack under the artwork layers.